# Is it possible to 3D print a front bumper grille for a Honda Accord CL7?

Tags: print-material

I probably have to find out all the answers myself, but I could really use somebody else's experience.

- what material should I use, so the grill does not bend when exposed
  to the heat coming from the radiator
- I have to print the part in slices; what glue can I use to join them lately, again so it resists the heat from the radiator and doesn't catch fire
- is there maybe a CAD file describing this part, so I don't have to manually create it from scratch?

Comment: I would recommend against doing this as it'll probably void your insurance if you use a non-approved material and process (which includes bonding parts together).  The last thing you want is something which has a lower flash point than the OEM grille, for example.  Much more sensible to find one at a salvage yard or eBay

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: yes, that's what I was thinking as well. Unfortunately, as one of second hand parts dealer told me, cars tend to crash frontally which means it is extremely hard to find these parts in good condition :-|

Comment: If you really want to make it your self I would suggest printing a mould for the bumper would be easier, then you could try making the part with fiber glass or some other material, and you could embed an aluminium or steel frame to provide strength and attachment points.

Comment: @user802599: please create an answer, I'll mark it as such. Thank you very ,very much for your suggestion, I think it's a bright idea.

Comment: Regarding the heat from the radiator. Place your hand where the grill will be. If it's not too hot for your hand, it won't be too hot for your 3D printed part. Also consider that the cooling fan is pulling air through the radiator, away from the grille, keeping the heat from reaching it, generally speaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet for the material would be one of the high temperature filaments like the ColorFabb HT ones, they can take quite a punch when it comes to heat.

As for the model, you could try to source one of the grills that is at least as good in shape as possible and get it scanned, there are people offering this as a service for example over at 3dhubs.com

Glue is really depending on the part, I would suggest creating a click-together type of system so the "glue" is only stabilizing it and not beeing a structural component. You can also get hold of a 3D Pen and weld the parts together with the same material used to print.